# Fermat's Little Theorem

Tags: cryptography

How do you compute the following using [Fermat's Little Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem)?

```
2^1,000,006 mod 101
2^-1,000,005 mod 11
```

Comment: You could add some more info how you tried to solve this and where your problems are, instead of just posting the plain homework question...

Comment: Upvoted for the validity of the question. If you don't understand the core process, there's no way to "begin" this problem. It's two steps roughly, so explain how we was supposed to "start."

Comment: Why is there a negative sign in the second equation? Someone please explain, it doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Division is well-defined in finite fields, and arithmetic modulo a prime is a finite field. 2^-1 is the integer which, when multiplied by 2 mod 11, gives the result 1. Which is to say, 2^-1 is 6 mod 11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know that a^(p-1) === 1 mod p, so...

2^10 === 1 mod 11
2^(-1,000,005) = 2^(-1,000,000)*2^(-5) = 1 * 2^(-5) = 2^(-5)*2^(10) = 32 mod 11 = -1 = 10

From this, can you see how to work the larger number? The process is the same.

It's FLT all the way. I messed up.

Comment: I don't think 2^-5 === 2^6 (mod 11).

Comment: Yeah, there's definitely some errors in this (or at least bad notation). Needs to be corrected, but I'm not sure where to begin.

Comment: so then 2^1,000,006 mod 101...
2^1,000,000 * 2^6 = 1 * 32 = 32 mod 101 = -5?

Comment: Does Fermat little theorm give Correct Answer for any integer? If Not, till how many digits it can give accurate solution?

Answer (score 2):

Since 101 and 11 are prime, then (respectively) 2^100 and 2^10 are congruent to 1 mod 101 and 11.

Try to express 2^1000006 in terms of 2^100 and 2^-1000005 in terms of 2^10. You should be able to reduce each problem to something easy to calculate.

Comment: This seems to be the way to go. Additionally, it only guides the OP, so good answer.